# Logging/print statements do not work in subprocess in Python Django application

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, logging

In my Django project I have a file called `views.py`. There are a couple of logging/print statements there, which work fine.

However, `views.py` calls another python script using subprocess’s `run` method. Surprisingly, no logging/print statements work in that script.
This is how `run()` is being called:

```
out= run([sys.executable, /path/to/script.py, param1, param2], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
```

Logging is configured like this in settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'my_logger': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
}
```

Please advise what is going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `subprocess.run` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, you have to display the standard streams from the invoked script yourself. The following is how you should be capturing those print statements:

```
p = run(
    [sys.executable, /path/to/script.py, param1, param2],
    shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE
)
# Display the contents of the standard output
print(p.stdout.read())
# Display the contents of the standard error
print(p.stderr.read())
```

Please note that `p` here is an instance of [`CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess). That means that you can use it to check whether or not the command you ran was successful by invoking `p.returncode`, which should contain the return code of the script that ran.

If you do not wish to capture the standard streams and display their contents yourself, consider invoking the script ***without*** setting `stdout` and `stderr` to `PIPE`:

```
p = run(
    [sys.executable, /path/to/script.py, param1, param2], shell=False
)
```

This should force the standard streams (`stdout` and `stderr`) to be displayed when the script is run.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any option other than stdout=subprocess.PIPE, which will allow me to use print statements in the script itself?

Comment: Leaving `stdout` and `stderr` unset should force `subprocess.run` to print the contents of the standard streams. Please see my edits.

Comment: Many thanks. This solution was perfect for me!